# How does $ f_{( T_1, T_2 )} (t_1, t_2 ) = \frac {\partial ^2 }{ \partial t_1 \partial t_2 } \mathbb P ( T_1 > t_1 , T_2 > t_2 )$?

Tags: calculus, probability

I saw that expression in a paper :

$$ f_{( T_1, T_2 )} (t_1, t_2 )= \frac {\partial ^2 }{ \partial t_1 \partial t_2 }  \mathbb P ( T_1 > t_1 , T_2 > t_2 )$$

And it seems to me that it is false. The algebra is so simple that I can't figure out where I could be wrong.

Basically, I think that :

$$ f_{( X )} (x) \text{ ?=? } \frac {\partial }{  \partial x }  \mathbb P ( X > x ) = \frac {\partial }{  \partial x }   1 - \mathbb P ( X \leq x ) = - f_{( X )} (x)  $$

Am I wrong ? Is it possible for the first expression to be correct?

Comment: You are correct, but note that $(-1) \cdot (-1) = 1$, so this does not prove that the expression is false (maybe differentiating second time will cancel it out)

Comment: In my opinion, the initial derivation was equivalent to the second where one sets as $X := (T_1,T_2)$ @DominikKutek

Comment: Not exactly @Marine Galantin, $\mathbb P(X > x) = 1 - \mathbb P(X \le x)$ doesn't work when $X=(T_1,T_2)$ and $x=(t_1,t_2)$ (if you assume that $X>x$ means $T_1>t_1, T_2>t_2$, because then complement is $T_1 \le t_1$ OR $T_2 \le t_2$, so it has more terms to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that derivatives of $\mathbb P(T_1 > t_1,T_2 > t_2)$ exist and the density of vector $(T_1,T_2)$ is $f_{(T_1,T_2)}$ we have by Fubini and Schwarz rule (about order of differentiating):

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t_2} \frac{\partial}{\partial t_1} \mathbb P(T_1 > t_1, T_2 > t_2) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t_2} \frac{\partial}{\partial t_1} \int_{t_1}^\infty \int_{t_2}^\infty f_{(T_1,T_2)}(x,y)dydx $$

Now by fundemental rule of calculus, setting $G(t)$ be such that $G'(t)= \int_{t_2}^\infty f_{(T_1,T_2)}(t,y)dy$  we get:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t_2} \frac{\partial}{\partial t_1} G(\infty) - G(t_1) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t_2} G'(t_1) = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t_2} \int_{t_2}^\infty f_{(T_1,T_2)}(t_1,y)dy $$

Apply that rule one more time to function $H(t)$ such that $H'(t) = f_{(T_1,T_2)}(t_1,t)$ getting:

$$ - \frac{\partial}{\partial t_2} H(\infty) - H(t_2) = (-1) \cdot (-H'(t_2)) = H'(t_2) = f_{(T_1,T_2)}(t_1,t_2)$$

Comment: how do you justify rigorously commutting limit and derivative ? Since we're dealing with pdf/cdfs, the limit exists and is finite?

Comment: For example in Rudin, it is shown that $\frac{d}{d_t}\int_t^\infty f(x)dx = -f(t)$ for measurable function $f$. In our case with $G$ it is even simplier (because $G'$ is continuous,monotonically decreasing and integrable). Note that $G(\infty)=0$ exists). With $H$ I used the above fact (note that $H(\infty) = 0$ since $f$ is integrable.)